# ¿como convertir json a texto plano node js?

Tags: json, nodejs

¿Hay alguna manera de convertir un json a texto plano ya que al consumir el servicio me regresa un json y quiero regresar un texto plano, en donde tengo que configurar el codigo y que ponerle.

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar mas contenido a tu pregunta?, te recomiendo leer [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Un JSON ya es un string.
Para convertirlo a un objeto puedes usar la funcion de JavaScript `JSON.parse()`:

```
const obj = JSON.parse(textoJson);
```